# Storing Integer in Keychain Swift

Tags: swift, keychain, userdefaults

I'm trying to implement a trial in an app. In the trial the user would get to use a functionality (like creating a note) a certain number of items. I am currently storing the trials item count in `UserDefaults`.

The problem is in iOS UserDefaults data is cleared and when the user reinstalls the app the trial renews.

I want to allow one trial per device in which the trial note count should continue from the stored value after reinstall.

One way this could be achieved is, storing the value in `KeyChain` recording the note count. So my question is, are non password values allowed to be stored in `KeyChain` OR is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you take a look into [In-App Purchase](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/)?

Comment: I think you are suggesting consumable in-app purchases. The app already has subscriptions. After the allowed quota is up the user is requested to subscribe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly spoken you cannot save integers in the keychain.

But you can convert the integer to `String` and store it either as **password** or along with other data in JSON format as **Secure Note**.

Comment: But will updating the keychain value every time be ideal?

Comment: Why not? Another way could be a communication with a web server

Comment: Asking because keychain is usually meant for storing passwords and such.

Comment: Also storing the integer as a string wouldn't help because I would need an integer for comparison with the limit.

Comment: Secure Notes are for storing sensitive data which are not passwords. And it's pretty simple to convert `Int` to `String` and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

After using Apple's KeyChain API for some time I ended up using external library called `KeyChainSwift`for handling with `KeyChain` and so much of my problems just disappeared. For example storing value of any kind (also Integer) in Keychain. Here is link for cocapods library [KeyChainSwift](https://cocoapods.org/pods/KeychainSwift) , and here is simple tutorial for using it : [KeychainSwift tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1R-VIzjD4yo)